# A question about source code of Collection.contains(Object o) in ArrayList;

Tags: java

**The following is the source code for Conlletion.contains(Object o) in ArrayList:**

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element
 * in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.
 * More formally, returns the lowest index <tt>i</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>,
 * or -1 if there is no such index.
 */
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**I want to know why not type check first,for example:**

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if(o.getClass() != elementData[0].getClass())
         return false;
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}
```

**This is more efficient when o is a different type,isn't it?**
(ps:Sorry, my English is not very good, I don't know if I speak clearly)

Comment: If `o` is null then you will get NullPointerException

Comment: This is not the key, adding a null pointer detection is simple.The key question is why not type check

Comment: [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is an interface, and it doesn't have an implementation of the *abstract* `contains(Object o)` method. The code you've shown seems to be from the `ArrayList` class, not the `Collection` interface.

Comment: I think no harm in adding that check, but how you will check the type. You are just checking first element elementData[0], what if other elements are of different type. I think checking that will add more complexity than you think. In general thats why generics were introduced for type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Since `elementData` is always allocated as an `Object[]`, the expression `elementData.getClass().getComponentType()` is the same as `Object.class`, so `if (o.getClass() != elementData.getClass().getComponentType())` would pretty such always be true, i.e. `contains()` would pretty such **always return false**.

Your suggestion wouldn't work, that's why it's not done that way.

---

Besides, even if you could, it still wouldn't work, because the values of a `Collection` object can be any **subclass** of the type specified for the collection.

E.g. an `ArrayList<Number>` can contain a mix of `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, ... objects, so even if `elementData.getClass().getComponentType()` would have returned `Number.class`, it would still be a bad type check.

Comment: @yang No! See second half of answer. Just because the first object in the list is e.g. a `Double`, doesn't mean all the objects are.

Comment: Actually, in most cases checking for type inequality can be used to short circuit the equality check. But this decision cant be taken over by a library function since it does not generally apply.

Comment: @Vitaliy Since just about every `equals` implementation in the Java universe does exactly that, i.e. start with a type check, you point would be? That for the `contains` method to do so too, for every element, would be redundant and a waste of processing power? If so, yeah; but that's not what you said, so what was the point of your comment?

Answer (score -1):

I am only guessing but I think it was an api design decision.
Since Java supports overwriting the equals method- it is up to the programmer to decide what it means for two objects to be equal. In theory, two objects of different types can be considered equal in a certain domain. It is true that checking for type equality is *common* when implementing equals, but it is not a *mandatory*. Since *contains* is a method for the most general case, no assumptions were made regarding the domain it would be called in.

Comment: It's not an API decision, it's a bad suggestion that **assumes** that all the elements in the collection are of the same type. They don't have to be. See second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58534514/5221149).

Comment: @andreas, I did not suggest all elements are of the same type. But since you raised it, most often than not type difference will suggest inequality. But not in the general case. Thia is the point of my answer.

Comment: You missed my point, in that it's not an *API decision*, it's an impossibility, and so there was no decision to make. Impossible because `elementData` is an `Object[]`, and hence there is no type to compare with, at the global level. It simply cannot be determined up front that the object passed to `contains` is of the wrong type, since erasure has discarded the needed information. Since it's not an API decision, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @andreas, dont underrstand what erasure has to do with it, the type information is available at *runtime*.

Comment: No it ain't. `new ArrayList<Number>(15)` means to create a list with capacity for 15 elements, so it will do `elementData = new Object[15]`, not `new Number[15]`, because **type erasure** has eliminated the `Number` type. Which means that the entire premise of the question, i.e. calling `elementData.getClass().getCompoentType()` is *meaningless*, as it's just going to return `Object.class`. It is **impossible** to know, at runtime, what the defined genetic type of the `ArrayList` is, especially since `Number` is abstract, so it'll only contain objects of **subclasses**.

Comment: The change to the question, using `elementData[0].getClass()` instead, won't work either, Because that will return the type of an actual element, not the declared generic type of the `ArrayList`. E.g. `ArrayList<Number>` may contain a `Double` in the first position, so calling `elementData[0].getClass()` gets you `Double`, but how does that help? How can you type check that the `contains` parameter must be a `Number`? You'd end up rejecting a `Long` parameter value (`Long != Double`), even though that value might actually be in the list. It's **impossible** to do an upfront type-check.